# Varnishhist x- and y-axis

Tags: varnish

In varnishhist the x-axis shows the time varnish took between getting the request from the kernel and sending it back to kernel.

The y-axis shows the number of requests.

```
| => cache hit
# => cache miss
```

That is what I understood from the manpage. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Yet there is one thing I'm unsure about. The pipes (|) on the far left side, do they also stand for cache hits or are they just there to print the y-axis? I'm voting for the latter, but would like to be sure.

Comment: Just to put this in one place .. According to http://www.mail-archive.com/varnish-misc@projects.linpro.no/msg03528.html **The x-axis shows (oversimplified) the number of seconds it takes Varnish to 'get the result', either from the backend or from its cache.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a vertical stack of pipes in the leftmost column.

My display is like so:

```
1:50, n = 2000


                |
                |
                |
                |
                |
                |
                |
                |
                |
                |
                |
                |
                |
                |
                |
                |
                |
                |
                |
                |
                |
                |
                |
                |
               |||           ##                   #
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------
|1e-6    |1e-5    |1e-4    |1e-3    |1e-2    |1e-1    |1e0     |1e1     |1e2
```

(Varnish 2.1.3 BTW)

Comment: I do have a lot of pipes right above the plus sign next to 1e-6. If you don't have them they seem to be some requests. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

Even more useful details about how to read *'varnishhist'* output can be found in answered question [How to Read a Varnish Histogram](https://serverfault.com/questions/304181/how-to-read-a-varnish-histogram/538206).