# How to Read a Varnish Histogram?

Tags: varnish, graph

How is a varnishhist histogram/graph read? I understand that the x-axis is a log scale.

Specifically:

- I see 9 "|"s or cache hits occur around `y=1e-4`, what does each "|" refer to? Page? File?
- I see fewer hits to the left of these 9 "|"s and some to the right. What are those? Did they take longer (right) and shorter (left) time ... ?
- In the top, left what are `1:2`? and `n = 134`
- Also, I've noticed that the cache hits are always to the left of the cache misses, i.e., they are on the `1e-x` side of things, while cache misses are under + exponent. What is the significance of that? Is that time, if so, time of what ... ?

Many Thanks!

x-axis

```
1:2, n = 134                                                              hostname








                            #
                            #
                            #
                            #
                            #
                   |        #
                   |        #
                   |        #
                   |        #
                   |       ###
                   |       ###
                  ||       ###                              ##
                  |||      ###         ## #   #             ##
                  ||||     ####      #### ## ##  #          ###
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------
|1e-6     |1e-5     |1e-4     |1e-3     |1e-2     |1e-1     |1e0      |1e1  |1e2
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So the x-axis is the time it takes for the request to come into varnish and get sent back to the client. The |'s are the cache hits and the #'s are the misses. So you should see all the |'s on the left since that is a faster time.

So the left most numbers are faster.. the right most are slower..

now the 1:2 n= number.. Its numbers for the vertical scale and sample size. I wouldn't worry much about those.

But from that output.. you have a pretty fast cache going on.

Comment: Thanks @Mike. There isn't much going on this box yet (-: So I take it, the x-axis is in seconds ... ?

Comment: yes.. 1e0 = 1 second

Comment: Actually, I am more intrigued by `1:2, n=_num_` (_: Any ideas what that represents?

Comment: it's just numbers how the graph is scaled.. has nothing to do with how varnish is performing

Answer (score 18):

- **'|'** is cache **HIT**
- **'#'** is cache **MISS**
- **'n:m'** numbers in left top corner is **vertical scale**
- **'n = 123'** is **number of requests** that are being displayed
- **X-axis** is logarithmic time between request request from kernel to Varnish and response from Varnish to kernel.

The X-axis works like this:

- 1e1 = 10 sec
- 1e0 = 1 sec
- 1e-1 = 0.1 secs or 100 ms (milliseconds)
- 1e-2 =  0.01 secs or 10 ms
- 1e-3 = 0.001 secs or 1 ms or 1000 µs (microseconds)
- 1e-4 = 0.0001 secs or 0.1 ms or 100 µs
- 1e-5 = 0.00001 secs or 0.01 ms or 10 µs
- 1e-6 = 0.000001 secs or 0.001 ms or 1 µs or 1000 ns (nanoseconds)

Whole article explaining *'varnishhist'* very nicely can be found here: [Varnishhist – What Does it Tell Us](https://web.archive.org/web/20140117135527/http://zygmund.net/varnishhist-what-does-it-tell-us/), and official doc here: [Varnish request histogram](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/varnishhist.html).

Another useful command is *'varnishstat'* - Varnish Cache statistics.